# 'e is undefined' error when calling image()

Tags: javascript, p5.js

When I call image() from p5.js library, it gives me the type error 'e is undefined', despite giving it the image. I am fairly new to javascript, and completely new to p5.js. The idea is that I would get the following images to fall on the screen from a random x and y coordinate.

```
var yVal; 
var accel; 
var velocity; 
var mass; 
var pieces = []

function preload () {
   images = ["/images/L.png", "/images/LL.png", "/images/T.png"]
   img_amount = getRandomInt(21);
   for (var i = 1; i <= img_amount; i++) {
       var img = loadImage(images[getRandomInt(3)]);
       pieces[i-1] = img;
   }
}

function setup() {
 createCanvas(window.innerWidth, 700);

 yVal = [];  
 velocity = []; 
 mass = 10; 
 accel = mass * 0.1; 

 for (var i = 0; i <= img_amount; i++) {
   var randX = getRandomInt(window.innerWidth);
   var randY = getRandomInt(700);
   image(pieces[i], randX, randY, mass, mass);
 }
}

function draw() {
 background(25);
 fill(255,0,0);

  for (var i = 0; i <= img_amount; i++) {
    velocity[i] += accel;
    yVal[i] += velocity[i]; 
    image(pieces[i], pieces[i].xvalue, yVal[i], mass, mass);
    if (yVal[i] > height - mass/2) {
        // A little dampening when hitting the bottom
        velocity[i] *= -0.6;
        yVal[i] = height - mass/2;
    }
  }
}


function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using a minified version of the p5 library - try developing using the [uncompressed version](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/v1.4.1/p5.js)? This will give you a better idea of what/where the error is.

Comment: you create `pieces` using `for (var i = 1; i <= img_amount; i++)` ... so there's img_amount pieces stored in 0 ... img_amount-1 (since you use `i-1` as the index ... your other loops use pieces like `for (var i = 0; i <= img_amount; i++)` ... note the starting value is 0 here - so those loops are trying to access `piece[img_amount]` but the last piece is `piece[img_amount - 1]`